# To which of the angels did ELOHIM say at any time, You are MY son. Today have I begotten you… ? [Heb 1:5; Ps 2:7]

Tags: jesus, hebrews, pre-existence

Hebrews 1:1-2 declares - “ELOHIM, having in the past spoken to the fathers through the prophets at many times and in various ways,
1:2 has at the end of these days spoken to us by HIS Son, Whom HE appointed heir of all things, because of Whom also HE created the ages.” - Excerpt From
Book of The Covenant 5th Ed

Verse 1:2 says that the Son has been appointed (called, anointed) to speak to us at “the end of these (latter) days” (whereas in the past/ OT days, ELOHIM spoke to the patriarchs through the prophets only). This simply means that ELOHIM did not appoint (call, anoint) the Son to speak to the patriarchs in the past/ OT days (until the latter days). (As also illustrated by YaHshua’s parable about the landowner who sent his son (after various preceding servants) only at the end, to apprehend the tenants).

Concerning the nature and identity of Adon Mashiach, we know that His nature from Bethlehem to the tomb was a perfect human being and yet is ELOHIM’s only begotten Son. At His resurrection He was a glorified human being (first born of many brethren to come). Since then He is seated at the right hand of the ABBA, waiting to return for His Kingdom on earth. Question1: When Mashiach was resurrected with a glorified human body, is it His everlasting inheritance from His ABBA, or is it a temporary  transformation/ mode only? Question2: When Mashiach comes again (future), will He be coming with that same glorified human body (since His resurrection), or will He revert to some other pre-Bethlehem mode/ nature such as an “Angel-being (not human)”, a “Spirit-being (without body)”, etc? Question3: what do you reckon will be the ETERNAL STATE of the Messiah (Christ)- Spirit-being OR Glorified Human being?
Correct answer to above will show clearly the relationship between the Messiah and His ABBA ELOHIM.
Note: Jn 4:24 - ELOHIM is RUACH (Spirit. The Eternal One)

Comment: You are asking 'how' can 'people claim' ? This is therefore a matter of opinion. Here on SE-BH we deal with the text of scripture itself, not the motivation for certain 'claims' made by certain 'people'. Please see the Tour and the Help as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

Comment: It only refers to the revelation by prophets to the church in the old times, vs the direct revelation by the Son in the end times. The Son spoke to the fathers and he saved the Israelite from Egypt but he did not reveal himself to common men. He fully revealed himself as a prophet in the end.

Comment: @Michael16 Scripture is more discrete : the 'Angel of the Lord' is he who spoke. Or 'Elohim' spoke from within the bush as 'Jehovah' observed. Jesus Christ is _publicly_ declared to be the Son by the resurrection from the dead and by the first public preaching of Paul the Apostle.

Comment: @NigelJ the angel, elohim is the same Jesus who spoke with them and saved Moses and Israel. I agree about Jesus being handed the power after resurrection but what you said about Paul preaching first about preaching it is absurd. Paul is the last of all. He was Saul until his miraculous encounter. @ Gim read this whole site https://www.biblestudying.net/rabbinic4.html

Comment: @Michael16 Then I look forward to any prior reference (post-resurrection) to Jesus of Nazareth being 'the Son of God'.

Comment: Hebrews 1:1–2 doesn't use the word "ELOHIM"; it uses "theos" (θεός).  Is there a reason it has been changed to "ELOHIM" in the question?  Would the question be significantly different if it were changed back to "God"?

Comment: @NigelJ Mark 3:11: “And whenever the unclean spirits saw him, they fell down before him and cried out, “You are the Son of God.” ; Matt4:3, Luke 8:28, John 1:49

Comment: @Michael16 I was enquiring, regarding "post-resurrection" testimony.

Comment: @Nigel J Think the topic is about a claim, that according to my understanding is actually founded in the bible and so forms an aspect of Hermeneutics.

Comment: Hebrews doesn't have the word Elohim, so this is already using some odd paraphrase. Either way, I don't see how this question is about the meaning of Hebrews 1.

Comment: Fact is that the original language and culture of scripture is Hebraic (YAHudith to be precise). Even though the NT was penned in Greek, fact is that the people, culture and geography of all pertinent events and conversations as recorded/ testified by the writers, were all Hebraic (YAHudith) in nature and context. It behoved the writers to do what they can, using their own internal bi-lingual translation ability, or else external bi-lingual scribal assistance to translate the actual Hebraic proceedings/ conversations into the lingua franca of the day.

Answer (score 1):

This incarnation doesn't imply that the Son never spoke on behalf of God before it occurred, only that before this point, the Son was not sent as a subservient (as it were) messenger, but as the glorified God (Genesis 32:30; John 12:41), whereas with the incarnation, there is a subservience inherent in taking on the human nature and ministry. I think the emphasis of Hebrews therefore is on the fact that the *identity* of the messenger is no longer merely angel or prophet, but of the very Son of God Himself—as incarnate and subserient, yet as God's eternal Son as to His actual personal identity (i.e. who he is—not a creature of Mary's womb, but the Creator thereof) and not that messages from God have stopped, or that the Son didn't speak in *any* capacity. Suppose the Father were to become incarnate: He could say, although He spoke with people since the beginning of Creation, 'whereas before I spoke by prophets and angels, I now come to speak to you Myself.' By saying this, it wouldn't follow that He didn't speak before *in any capacity*, only that now *He has taken on the category of Messenger, rather than Message-originator*.

Comment: Based on Sola scripture principle, all substantial statements made must be supported by scripture accordingly. As example, one cannot used a substantial term like “God the Son”, without providing at least one verse that uses that term.

Comment: I'm not a Protestant (Sola Scriptura was a doctrine of the Reformation). And even then, only a minority of Protestants interpret Sola Scriptura to further mean 'you must only use the terms and phrases found in the Bible to describe the doctrines taught there.' Hardly any Protestant actually believes this. You also didn't limit your answers to answers by Protestants...

Answer (score 1):

The base of ´what people claim´ is, what Jesus states himself:

> John 8:58 Jesus said to them, “Truly, truly, I say to you, before Abraham
> was, I am.”

The actual answer is hidden on the Road to Emmaus

> Luke 24:15-16 As they talked and discussed these things with each other, Jesus himself came up and walked along with them;
> but they were kept from recognizing him.

Jesus appears as arbitrary bodies. According to John not limited in time, he can be assumed to be the one, who spoke to Abraham in Gen 18:

> 1 And the LORD appeared unto him in the plains of Mamre: and he sat in the tent door in the heat of the day; 2 And he lift up his eyes and looked, and, lo, three men stood by him: and when he saw them, he ran to meet them from the tent door, and bowed himself toward the ground

The meeting with Moses is during the transfiguration, Mt 17

> 3 Just then there appeared before them Moses and Elijah, talking with Jesus.

The Hebrew reference seems to address Jesus' central mission as Holy Lamb and founder (or re-newer) of the blood covenant with a specific occurrence in our timeline.

Here are more references
[Jesus in the Old Testament](https://www.gotquestions.org/Jesus-in-the-Old-Testament.html)

Comment: Interesting read the link you posted. Jesus was prophesied from Gen 3:15 - many OT writers wrote about the one to come  - not because he was already there. The Gospels explain how Jesus came to be- the logos become flesh, that was 2000 yrs ago.

Comment: @steveowen Consider God acting in HIS causality, implying an independent timeline, which does not follow the physical timeline. E.g. miracles occur, when God's will invokes and event in our timeline, a coincidence; reverse this does not limit him to the causality of our time axis.

Comment: Fascinating idea, but it is decidedly without scripture for clear support - so, it's just an idea without purpose.  *But reject foolish and ignorant speculation, for you know that it breeds quarrelling.* 2 Tim 2:23 gives all the guidance we need. We only need to look to the church fathers who entertained all manner of ideas not founded on the word, not that they were alone.

Answer (score -1):

**How can people claim that the Son of ELOHIM was actively speaking/ communicating with the patriarchs in the OT, in spite of Hebrews 1:1-2?**

Because people like to make up their own conclusions based on a faulty premise. For example,

> John 8:58 Jesus said to them, “Truly, truly, I say to you, before Abraham was, I am.”

We must be sure to understand the meaning intended and not make up our own conclusions that cause contradiction in scripture.

- what does "before" mean? many think it *has to mean* in time. Therefore Jesus pre-existed Abraham. It does not say this. Because there is a presupposed premise, the conclusion is then poorly obtained.

We are told plainly and consistently how, when, and by who and by what method, Jesus originated. It was not an incarnation because we are not told this - anywhere, nor is it inferred - unless we draw own conclusions based on speculation or inference.

> Matt 1:23 ‘Behold, the virgin shall conceive and bear a son, and they shall call his name Immanuel’
> Gal 4:4 But when the fullness of time had come, God sent forth His son, born of woman, born under the law.

> The Holy Spirit will come on you, and the power of the Most High will overshadow you. So the holy one to be born will be called the Son of God. Luke 1:35

-'before'

> Gal 3:16 Now the promises were spoken to Abraham and to his seed. It does not say "and to seeds" as of many but "and to your seed" as of one, who is Christ.

If Jesus is descended from Abraham, and of course David etc, how can he be before in time. When we have a sound overview of God’s plan from the beginning, Jesus was always going to come at the appointed time – his prominence and status as God’s only (sinless) son makes him before Abraham in every sense – except time. Although even in time, Jesus was *planned* from the start. He was *foreknown* by God, ‘before the foundation of the world’.

As the OP points out, Jesus is made heir and also depends on God for everything.

- His very existence through Mary - God.
- Raising him from the dead - God.
- Appointing him heir - God.
- Making him Lord and Christ - God.
- Granting him life as the Father has life - God.
- Sitting in heaven next to - God.
- All authority given by - God.
- Made High Priest - God.
- All Jesus' words and miracles - God.
- Anointed with holy spirit and power - God

And correctly notes that Heb does not say, "through whom He made the universe" but the *ages* - not world or universe. This is part of the bias introduced into the text to support the faulty premise, from which all manner of poor conclusions are drawn.

Comment: Agree with you reading of John 8:58, that the plan of God is eternal and so all biblical events foreseen. Still it says: "Jesus *is* in the past tense of Abraham", which is stronger than "Jesus *is planned* in the past tense of Abraham".

Comment: @SamGinrich It's so simple, right? He says, "*Because there is a presupposed premise, the conclusion is then poorly obtained*" about those who believe in Jesus' preexistence, without ever thinking to apply it to himself. Why does he look at the speck of sawdust in our eyes and pay no attention to the plank in his own eye? By far the most simple reading of John 8:58 is that Jesus WAS(past tense first- and third-person singular of "be") before Abraham. People like this will deny no matter what. They take a plain approach to a text when it suits them, but a not-so-plain approach when it doesn't.

Comment: @Rajesh *Steveowen* claims a presupposed premise, he can do this. I have no problem, reading the scripture as it comes to me, for me my interpretation makes sense and is consistent and I'm happy if the Spirit of God appears to others, in the way he decides to. I assume he does.

Comment: When we have one  or two verses that seems to say Jesus pre-existed or was in time before Abraham, then it must be interpreted by scripture and introduce no contradictions. By insisting Jesus is before A, it denies all the other texts mentioning his origin with Mary - at least - it makes them a lie or a 1/2 truth and that is not acceptable.  Quibbling about tenses in isolation, when the majority of scripture points to a different reality is not a 'sound biblical hermeneutic' approach.

Comment: @steveowen I have no problem with the two natures of Jesus as man and God. The man Jesus was spiritually received from Holy Spirit, born by Mary. Transfiguration and Resurrection are events of the development of man Jesus, while the Gospel of John re-displays Genesis from the view of God: The word became flesh. The resurrected Jesus seems to have no limit in space and time. When I pray to Jesus, I must assume his divinity, else I would violate the first commandment. When I assume divinity, there is no limit. If the scripture says, Jesus is before Abraham and Abraham saw man Jesus coming.

Comment: @steveowen "*Quibbling about tenses in isolation, when the majority of scripture points to a different reality is not a 'sound biblical hermeneutic' approach.*" The "majority" of scripture, huh? Socinians have to reconcile a LOT more passages with their doctrine than those who believe in the preexistence of Christ have to. By the way, you only give 3 passages; Matt 1:23, Gal 4:4, and Luke 1:35. That doesn't seem like the "majority". Also, you're strawmanning our position. "Jesus" was a human person who was born 2000 years ago and did not exist before then. This much is obvious.

Comment: "The Son", on the other hand, was NOT a man born 2000 years ago. "The Son" was a spirit being, just like God, or the angels, or the demons. He was in the "form" of God, which, by the way, simply means that He was a spirit being like God; angels and demons are *also* spirit beings. "The Son" had a "spirit", or an "animating force", just like every "living"(God is said to be "living"[Jeremiah 10:10, Matthew 16:16], even though He is clearly not "living" in the sense that humans and animals are) being has. "The Son" emptied Himself and let God put His "spirit" into a human embryo by means of HS.

Comment: If as claimed, Jesus pre-existed Bethlehem as an Angel of YHWH, then what is the point of YHWH’s rhetorical question - “1:5 For to which of the malachim did HE say at any time,  You are MY son. Today have I begotten you; and again,  I will be to him an ABBA, and he will be to ME a son? [Heb 1:5; Ps 2:7; 2Sa 7:14; 1Chr 17:13]”. This would be an invalid rhetorical question? YHWH will need to withdraw this question?